# Make an opt out for DM's

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I made a dm feature for anonymous messaging. Here is my code.

```py
@client.command(name="dm")
async def send_dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)  
    await ctx.send("Message sent")
```

I tried making a variable changing thing, but I'd have to create a new variable every time someone joined.

```py
user1 = True
user2 = True
user3 = False
user4 = True
user4 = False
```

I'd also need to have everyone redo it after an update.

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

To do this, you use `@commands.has_role("opt_in")`, if they have the role, then the DM is sent.

```py
@client.command(name="dm")
@commands.has_role("opt_in")
async def send_dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, content):
    channel = await member.create_dm()
    await channel.send(content)  
    await ctx.send("Message sent")
```

If the user does not have the role, then the message won't be sent.